# How do I code and analyze more than one set of treatments (e.g., intervention, implementation) within Difference-in-differences analysis?

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am working on a project in which I want to utilized difference-in-differences (DID) analysis to look at the impact of a county-level policy on rates of a social problem at the county level in a state within the United States.

I believe that I know how to run a DID analysis, but I could use some help. Up to this point, I know how to run DID with two groups (treatment and control) and one year of policy implementation, which means one year of pre- and one year of post-. But, in my current dilemma, I have two separate years of policy implementation. Thus, I am wondering how to run DID with more than one policy implementation year. To practice the DID approach, I have put together practice data so that I can get a handle on the overall process. The practice study is as follows: exploring the impact of county-level implementation of "Fake Policy" (this name is made-up) on county-level violent crime rates in Maryland, United States. I have extracted violent crime rates for each of Maryland's counties for 2012-2017. "Fake Policy" was implemented in 4 counties (Allegany, Anne Arundel, Baltimore, and Baltimore City) in 2013. "Fake Policy" was also implemented in 5 additional counties (St. Mary's, Talbot, Washington, Wicomico, and Worcester) in 2016. So, the timeline looks as follows:

[image]

At this point, I would know how to run a simple DID for one round of policy implementation at a time, such as below:

[image]

Below is the data that I have for this particular analysis:

[image]

I put the data into SPSS:

[image]

Create interaction:

[image]

Run Linear:

[image]

The aforementioned steps were just so I could get the process understood with only one year of policy implementation. So, within this post, I do not feel it necessary to repeat the aforementioned process for 2015-2017.

**Question**

The problem that I am facing is: How do I code the data and set up the analysis so that I account for BOTH (a) the implementation of "Fake Policy" in the 4 counties in 2013; and (b) the implementation of "Fake Policy" in 5 counties in 2016?

[image]

I have the data for all of the counties for 2012 to 2017 (See "Appendix" below).

Would anyone be so kind as to guide me through setting up the coding and analysis?

Appendix: Full Data

[image]